# Reaching xml tags with namespaces in python - jupyter

Tags: python, xml-parsing

Hello I try to parse this xml pasted below but my code doesn't return anything. Anyone can help me please?

```xml
<data>
<row>
<document>
<doc:document xmlns:ed="http://mail.yahoo.com/d/folders/1" xmlns:reslvd="http://mail.yahoo.com/d/folders/1/234" xmlns:ct="http://mail.yahoo.com/d/folders/cool/storybro" xmlns:doc="http://mail.yahoo.com/d/folders/nice/alldone">
<ed:EI>
<ed:SID>9865-346</ed:SID>
</doc:document>
</document>
</row>
</data>
```

my code is:

```py
x = []
for value in root.findall(".//*[@name='ed:SID']"):
    x.append(value.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your predicate is wrong: `//*[@name='ed:SID']` means: find any element which has an attribute called `name` and which itself has a value of `ed:SID`. Your sample xml doesn't have an element which meets these requirements.

Also, your sample xml is not well formed -`<ed:EI>` should be closed like this: `<ed:EI/>`.

Also, you have to [deal with the namespace.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces)

Finally, if I understand you correctly, this is what you're looking for:

```
for value in root.findall(".//{*}SID"):
   x.append(value.text)
print(x)
```

The output, given your sample xml, is

```
['9865-346']
```

Comment: actually i tried your code but didnt work in Jupyter, still gave me void list. Which platform did u try?

Comment: @CoolStoryBro Also on Jupyter; [you can also try it here.](https://trinket.io/python3/093417f9c8)

Comment: looks cool, thnx so much